# don't know how to install the latest version of Popcorn-Time

Tags: software-installation

I've already downloaded the latest version of Popcorn-Time and extracted the files, but I have no idea on how to proceed for the installation process.

Help please.

ky.

Comment: See the readme or install file inside the directory you extracted. If you want a better answer/comment the question is lacking a few vital piece: where did you download it from? Otherwise we need to guess.

Comment: Where from and what format have you downloaded?

Comment: from http://popcorn-time.to/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps,

1. Download Popcorn Time binaries

   `$ sudo mkdir /opt/popcorn-time`

   FOR 32-BIT SYSTEM EXECUTE:
   `sudo wget -qO- https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-32.tar.xz | sudo tar Jx -C /opt/popcorn-time`

   FOR 64-BIT SYSTEM EXECUTE:
   `sudo wget -qO- https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64.tar.xz | sudo tar Jx -C /opt/popcorn-time`
2. Create executable link

Now, that Popcorn Time binaries are in place, we will create a symbolic link of `/opt/popcorn-time/Popcorn-Time` binary to `/usr/bin/popcorn-time`. This will allow non-privileged users to start Popcorn Time via terminal without any additional configuration:

```
$  sudo ln -sf /opt/popcorn-time/Popcorn-Time /usr/bin/popcorn-time
```

3. Create Desktop Launcher

Use your favorite text editor eg. vim and create launcher shortcut. The below command uses vim editor to create new `/usr/share/applications/popcorntime.desktop` desktop entry:

`$ sudo vi /usr/share/applications/popcorntime.desktop`

4. Insert the following content into the above created file:

[Desktop Entry]  
Version = 1.0  
Type = Application  
Terminal = false  
Name = Popcorn Time  
Exec = /usr/bin/popcorn-time  
Icon = /opt/popcorn-time/popcorntime.png  
Categories = Application;

5. Lastly, download Popcorn Time's icon

$ sudo wget -q -O /opt/popcorn-time/popcorntime.png https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Popcorn_Time_logo.png

I have taken reference from this [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-popcorn-time-movie-player-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux).